# .ics file on outlook update same calendar without deleting old ones

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar, vcalendar

I would like to update my own outlook calendar without deleting old events, the calendar .ics file has a unique identifier (X-WR-RELCALID) , but the problem is that each day I generate the calendar with new different events (without old ones), so when I click the .ics file the next day the outlook prompts a message asking me to replace the existing outlook or create new one, so when I choose to replace, the outlook will delete old events (since they are not provided in that day).Is there a way to tell outlook not to delete the non-provided events and simply append the new events to the same calendar.
Note that I don't want the user to import the file manually, I want him to merely click the file

Answer (score 0):

The real unique identifier for calendar events is the UID, so as long as you generate new UIDs, there should not be any replacement.